# Does Erlang store the base of the number?

Tags: erlang

I am learning bin syntax in erlang, and one thing I don't quite understand. Is the "base" of the number part of that number or not?

E.g. if I say `2#10` - does Erlang store the fact that it's in base 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it does not. This is [handled by the private function `scan_number` in the `erl_scan` module](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/7b1cda1f97cd3ec91e7111b22aeffa3b5a6812f1/lib/stdlib/src/erl_scan.erl#L941-L989) (Erlang's Lexer) and it converts the `Base#Digits` tokens into a normal integer value, completely discarding the Base value.

```
1> erl_scan:string("10").
{ok,[{integer,1,10}],1}
2> erl_scan:string("2#1010").
{ok,[{integer,1,10}],1}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't. I can't think of any language which does.